# Using putty to log in VPS. I forgot username but when using root and one password I logged in successfully. How could I find the username?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I've got a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to log in through Putty but I forgot the username. I tried to log in with the username 'root' and the password got me logged in.

So I searched for some information to find the username.

I tried `/etc/passwd` but all the users listed seem not my username (I only have this one account).

```
root@vpn1:/usr# cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:998:998:System Message Bus:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:997:997:systemd Network Management:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:996:996:systemd Resolver:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:995:995:systemd Time Synchronization:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-coredump:x:994:994:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
syslog:x:101:105::/home/syslog:/usr/sbin/nologin
uuidd:x:102:107::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
bind:x:103:108::/var/cache/bind:/usr/sbin/nologin
_rpc:x:104:65534::/run/rpcbind:/usr/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:105:110::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
Debian-exim:x:106:111::/var/spool/exim4:/usr/sbin/nologin
fetchmail:x:107:65534::/var/lib/fetchmail:/bin/false
sshd:x:108:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I tried `getent passwd "username I guessed"` but did not work either.

I remember months ago I was not logging in with the username root, so there should be another username.

Is there any way that I could find my username? Thanks!

Comment: Checking `/etc/passwd` would generally be the right way. If the root account is active and uses your password then likely there is simply no other account.

Comment: Only `root` has an actual shell (`bash`) as the login shell. `nologin`, `false` and `sync` are not shells. If there is another user then [it's in "another castle"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702223/108618).

Comment: By convention, regular users have user IDs over 1000. There's none here. A regular user need not exist.